# How can I understand what this javascript timer means in detail?

Tags: javascript, timer

I created a countdown / timer a few weeks ago using Javascript. The code is also executed correctly by the browser.

Today I looked at the code again and I make notes (Javascript comments) to understand the code and what exactly it does and to better understand Javascrpit.

I'm stuck at the moment. Here's a small piece of code that I absolutely don't understand.

What does the modulo operator do with time? Seconds, minutes, hours...

What exactly does y do?
and why are tenary operators used?

I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me in their own words what exactly the code does. thanks

```
function timer() {
let seconds = count % 60;
let minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);

minutes %= 60;
hours %= 60; 

y = ((minutes>0) ? ((minutes>9) ? minutes : '0'+minutes) + ":" : "") 
y += (seconds>9 || minutes == 0) ? seconds : '0'+seconds;
```

Same Code with my Comments :)

```
function timer() {
// SET VARIABLE FOR SECONDS = DONT KKNOW WHAT count % 60 means ???
let seconds = count % 60;
// SET VARIABLE FOR MINUTES = DONT KKNOW WHAT Math.floor(count / 60) means ???
let minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
// SET VARIABLE FOR MINUTES = DONT KKNOW WHAT Math.floor(minutes / 60) ???
let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);

// WHY USING %= OPERATER ???
minutes %= 60;
hours %= 60; 

// DONT UNDERSTAND Y ??? WHY USING TENARY OPERATORS ???
y = ((minutes>0) ? ((minutes>9) ? minutes : '0'+minutes) + ":" : "") 
y += (seconds>9 || minutes == 0) ? seconds : '0'+seconds;
```

EDIT: count = 3600 SECONDS

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder I googled `js percent operator`

Comment: *WHY USING %= OPERATER* what an odd question about code you wrote yourself. You used iit because it is appropriate to do so

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes i wrote this code but honestly this part of the code i just found here on stackoverflow, copy & paste for some weeks ago. I just want to understand the code better. Sorry that you dont like my question...

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain what `count` is, but it would appear to be a duration in seconds.

The modulo operator and the `floor(a/b)` operations are being used to convert the duration in seconds into a base-60 (i. e. Sumerian) representation, i. e., in hours, minutes, and seconds.

`y` is being built up to show the hours, minutes, and seconds as two decimal digits each, separated with colons, as is conventional to represent a time duration in hours, minutes, and seconds. So, for example, the final value might be "6:01:02" for six hours, one minute, and two seconds. For each base-sixty "digit", we want two decimal digits. The normal conversion of numbers to decimal notation does not include any leading zeros. If the answer were to have only one decimal digit, we have to append one leading zero to the beginning. So, for example, for 8, we would like to see "08".

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful. I have to learn more about Tenary Operators :) 
But the code becomes more understandable to me.

Comment: Yes, the ternary is just like `if` except for expressions rather than commands. It says, if the condition is satisfied, use the middle expression, otherwise, use the last expression.